# Swift - Remove the OauthProvider "continue to the app" screen twitter auth

Tags: swift, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

Unlike google and facebook auth, the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/twitter-login) recommend us to use OAuthProvider(providerID: ) function to login with twitter.

But when using this, there is a screen presented before twitter's, showing a "continue to the app" blue button.

[image]

Is there any way to **remove** this screen?

Sample code:

```
import FirebaseAuth
private var oauthProvider: OAuthProvider!

private func performOAuthLoginFlow(for provider: String, completion:  @escaping (_ credential: AuthCredential?, _ error: String?, _ user: User?)->Void) {

  oauthProvider = OAuthProvider(providerID: provider)
  oauthProvider.customParameters = ["force_login":"true"]

  oauthProvider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
    guard error == nil else { return completion(nil, error?.localizedDescription, nil) }
    guard credential != nil else { return completion(nil, "Credential empty", nil) }
    credentialLogin(with: credential!, for: provider) { authResult, error in
      completion(authResult?.credential, error, authResult?.user)
    }
  }       
}
    
private func credentialLogin(with credential: AuthCredential, completion:  @escaping (_ result: AuthDataResult?, _ error: String?)->Void){
  Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { result, error in
    guard error == nil else {
      return completion(nil, error?.localizedDescription)
    }
    completion(result, nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way as of today. Looks like Firebase team has been aware of the issue but they don't have any plans yet.
 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6233